# Why isn't this HTML5 canvas displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
c = getElementById('canvas');
ctx = c.getContext("2d")'
ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" height ="100" width = "100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this on Chrome and IE 9, and neither of them display anything. Do you know why doesn't this work?

It's probably something stupid, and my friend is asking me to post this as he's too lazy to sign up, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put your code in a `onload` function.

For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
};
```

The reason for this is because you javascrpt code will be running **before** the `<canvas>` renders, and you want it to run **afterwords**.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nCf7Y/

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error here:

```
ctx = c.getContext("2d")'
```

Change to:

```
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

Also, you need to use the document object:

```
c = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing 'document'.

`var c = document.getElementById('canvas');`

Answer (score 2):

The canvas is not there when the script is running. Move the `<canvas>` tag so that it is *before* the `<script>` tag.